# Laravel 7 : how to use set Active class By Segments

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using [this code](https://codeburst.io/just-in-case-laravel-handling-active-menu-item-932afe59cf9b) for set active class in nav menu But it does not work

```
function setActiveBySegments(string $path, string $class_name = "is-active")
 {
   $request_path = implode('/', Request::segments());

   return $request_path === $path ? $class_name : "";
 }
```

and in my nav.blade.php for edit Route

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/101/edit

```
<li class="{{ setActiveBySegments('admin/users/*/edit','active') }}">
```

Comment: Hi Nima. Thanks for your question. To construct a good question, please try to avoid saying things like 'it does not work'. Instead, describe in detail what results you are receiving against what results you are expecting. Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to be able to use a wildcard it would seem the `is` method on `Request` would work just fine:

```
function isActive($path, $class = 'active')
{
    return Request::is($path) ? $class : '';
}
```

> "The `is` method allows you to verify that the incoming request path matches a given pattern. You may use the `*` character as a wildcard when utilizing this method"

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Requests - Request Path & Method - Retrieving The Request Path](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#request-path-and-method) `is`